# Not able to display more than 6 names in x axis of chart control of report in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I am facing one problem while using  `asp.net Chart Control`..i am trying to import column values from `sql server` database for creating a report  and to **display the values in form of graph in chart** but I am having more than 13 names to display in  x axis as team name but I am not able to display **more than 6 names in x axis** it is displaying names alternatively I have tried increasing chart size but still facing the same issue kindly help.  ***Is there anyway to do it easily?***

**kindly refer the images**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: thr is no code I have used dataset in asp.net to link it with sql server and then added report in website

Comment: I think you are not selecting all columns ,there is no clue to examine .